# Issue using xpath with appium for native android apps

Tags: android, appium

I am having an issue with using xpath in my scripts. When I use the Appium inspector to locate and element using this xpath ***"//android.widget.TextView[@text='My Messages']"*** the inspector locates it with no problems. But when I try to use that xpath in my code like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='My Messages']")).click();
```

I get and error message that says

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
>   located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 20.16 seconds For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.42.2', revision:
>   '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03
>   10:52:47' System info: host: 'C02P98XHG3QD', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name:
>   'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_79' Session ID: 0701451b-c82d-7899-6030-099e74bc9fd4 Driver
>   info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Am I doing something wrong, or could this be an issue with Appium. I am currently using version 1.4.8

Comment: make sure your xpath is correct.

Comment: the xpath is correct . I use the same xpath when using the the appium inspector locator and it finds it fine.

Comment: Were you able to find the cause? We seem to be running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use name. Use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.TextView' and @text='My Messages']")).click();
```

Comment: this element doesn't have a name attribute. The my messages is the text.

Comment: That still doesn't work.  No matter what xpath I try it just never seems to find the element. But the inspector locator has no problem finding the element